# Paypal currency MXN problems

Tags: python, paypal

I'm working with Python a PayPal Api for payments.

I have a simple request with the field currency in USD and everything it's ok...

BUT if I change for MXN(I need with this currency) the paypal WS return this error:

```
{u'message': u'Invalid request - see details', u'debug_id': u'2c9a227257a86', u'information_link': u'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR', u'name': u'VALIDATION_ERROR', u'details': [{u'field': u'transactions[0].amount.currency', u'issue': u'Value is not supported at this time'}]}
```

I too try with Euro (EUR) and Japanese yen(JPY). It work perfect with this values...the problem is when I use MXN.

This is my request in Python :

```
ayment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [{
            "credit_card": {
                "type": "visa",
                "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "expire_month": "11",
                "expire_year": "2018",
                "cvv2": "xxx",
                "first_name": "Brad",
                "last_name": "John"}}]},
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1",
                "currency": "MXN",
                "quantity": 1 }]},
        "amount": {
            "total": "1",
            "currency": "MXN"},
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description."}]})
```

Any suggestions?

PD: The documentation mentions the MXN between the types of currencies supported

Answer (score 0):

Your account needs to be enabled for the MXN currency. If you're still getting the error after verifying, you should contact [Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask) with the `debug_id` in the response. They'll be able to see what's actually happening with your account.

Answer (score 0):

Theres is one problem with the price in the item_list because it should have float format (1.00) and the same for the item inside the items array.

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [{
            "credit_card": {
                "type": "visa",
                "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "expire_month": "11",
                "expire_year": "2018",
                "cvv2": "xxx",
                "first_name": "Brad",
                "last_name": "John"}}]},
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "MXN",
                "quantity": 1 }]},
        "amount": {
            "total": "1.00",
            "currency": "MXN"},
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description."}]})
```

Also you tried to create a credit card payment method,but Paypal just receive **paypal** payment method for MXN currency.

Hope it helps